# Why would screen brightness not adjust ofter closing laptop lid?

Tags: laptop, display, brightness, settings

Brightness adjustment works until I close my laptop. After I close it once I cannot adjust the brightness.

I often restart the computer to be able to adjust again.
The Fn Keys do not work. The Brightness and Lock settings don't respond.

There must be a better way.

- Toshiba, Portege.

Here is the etc/acpi/lid.sh read out. Could I adjust it?

```
    #!/bin/bash
# TODO:  Change the above to /bin/sh

test -f /usr/share/acpi-support/state-funcs || exit 0

. /usr/share/acpi-support/power-funcs
. /usr/share/acpi-support/policy-funcs
. /etc/default/acpi-support

[ -x /etc/acpi/local/lid.sh.pre ] && /etc/acpi/local/lid.sh.pre

if [ `CheckPolicy` = 0 ]; then exit; fi

grep -q closed /proc/acpi/button/lid/*/state
if [ $? = 0 ]
then
    for x in /tmp/.X11-unix/*; do
    displaynum=`echo $x | sed s#/tmp/.X11-unix/X##`
    getXuser;
    if [ x"$XAUTHORITY" != x"" ]; then
        export DISPLAY=":$displaynum"       
        . /usr/share/acpi-support/screenblank
    fi
    done
else
    for x in /tmp/.X11-unix/*; do
    displaynum=`echo $x | sed s#/tmp/.X11-unix/X##`
    getXuser;
    if [ x"$XAUTHORITY" != x"" ]; then
        export DISPLAY=":$displaynum"
        grep -q off-line /proc/acpi/ac_adapter/*/state
        if [ $? = 1 ]
        then
        if pidof xscreensaver > /dev/null; then 
            su $user -c "xscreensaver-command -unthrottle"
        fi
        fi
        if [ x$RADEON_LIGHT = xtrue ]; then
        [ -x /usr/sbin/radeontool ] && radeontool light on
        fi
        if [ `pidof xscreensaver` ]; then
        su $user -c "xscreensaver-command -deactivate"
        fi
        su $user -c "xset dpms force on"
    fi
    done
fi
[ -x /etc/acpi/local/lid.sh.post ] && /etc/acpi/local/lid.sh.post
```

Comment: When you open or close the lid, `/etc/acpi/lid.sh` gets run. It's probably to blame for the problem.

Comment: Are you saying I could adjust this text to re-obtain my brightness adjustment capability?

Comment: No, I'm saying you could read `/etc/acpi/lid.sh`, figure out what it does, and why that makes subsequent brightness adjustments "not work".

Comment: @waaltinator unfortunately I'm still learning how to code, would you know what might be giving me my problem

Comment: Nope. I think you'll have to describe your hardware more exactly (see this http://askubuntu.com/questions/14008/i-have-a-hardware-detection-problem-what-logs-do-i-need-to-look-into), and hope for help.

If you're still learning to code, DO NOT change the file!! Please - you risk getting your system into "it's broken and I can't communicate!" mode, and being very unhappy.

Comment: @waltinator any hardware specifics or should I just post my entire machine?

Comment: Don't "post your entire machine"! Read this link(http://askubuntu.com/questions/14008/i-have-a-hardware-detection-problem-what-logs-do-i-need-to-look-into). Read your `/var/log/pm-powersave.log` and `/var/log/pm-suspend.log` and maybe post them.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with a Toshiba Portege R935, and I discovered this (not so elegant) workaround:

- as root change the value in
  `sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness`

  for example:

  ```
  echo 3000 > /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness
  ```

**Warning**: these values are not between `0` and `7` (as the ones in `sys/class/backlight/toshiba/), but between`284`and`4539`, or something like that.